# getting 'file in use by another process' exception when checking file.exist

Tags: .net, file-io

i am getting exception 'file in use by another process' for a xml file when checking system.io.file.exist() & then load it.I am using thread.monitor with this code.

Earlier when i was directly loading the xml file & not checking its local existence then i ws not getting thsi exception.

Can you please let me know, what's the cause for this 'file in use by another process' exception even when thread.monitor is applied !!

thanks in advance

gbhatnagar

Comment: How are you using the monitor, can you post some code please?

Comment: Are you sure all of your i/o code is disposing of its objects properly?  You could also try Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what process has the file.

Answer (score 0):

**here is my code,**

Dim doc As XmlDocument = Nothing
Try
 doc = New XmlDocument  
 
 If (System.IO.File.Exists(logFile)) Then
     doc.Load(logFile)
 Else
     Dim objPI As Object = Nothing
     Dim objPII As Object = Nothing
     objPI = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
     objPII = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='" & _sXLSTPath & "'")
     doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Errors"))
     doc.InsertBefore(objPII, doc.ChildNodes(0))
     doc.InsertBefore(objPI, doc.ChildNodes(0))
 End If
 Catch exExceptionHandler As Exception
     **'write the exception in a text file**
 Return
End Try 
//proceed with code to add elements in xml & write